# Angular 2: Check if input in reactive form is empty, enter default value if no input given

Tags: angular, typescript

**Edit 2:** Improved upon the partial solution and now it's a complete solution. Yay!

**Edit:** Found an almost complete solution. It works, but not quite the way I want it.

1. It sets a default value from the moment the form is loaded. (not ideal)
2. It no longer returns null if the input is empty/deleted (returns an empty string instead)

The solution is posted after the text below.

---

I'm a new student to Angular and I'm making a simple CRUD app to understand how the language works. Currently, I'm learning how to do form validations.

As mentioned in the title, I want to have a validation method that checks if the input is empty, and if it is then to enter a default value. I'm looking for a clean and simple way to do this. Currently here is my code.

**`partial post.component.html`** (sorry about the multiple lines for the `<input>`element; I find it easier to read this way)

```
<modal #modal>
    <form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(postForm)" [formGroup]="postForm">
        <modal-header [show-close]="true">
            <h4 class="modal-title">{{modalTitle}}</h4>
        </modal-header>
        <modal-body>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div>
                    <span>Post Title</span>
                    <input [(ngModel)]="TitleText"
                           type="text" class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Post Title"
                           formControlName="PostTitle">
                    <div class="error"
                         *ngIf="postForm.get('PostTitle').hasError('required') && postForm.get('PostTitle').touched">
                        Title is required
                    </div>
                    <div class="error"
                         *ngIf="postForm.get('PostTitle').hasError('minlength') && postForm.get('PostTitle').touched">
                        Minimum title length is three (3) characters
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Post Slug</span>
                    <input [ngModel]="TitleText | slugify"
                           type="text"
                           class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Post Slug"
                           formControlName="PostSlug">
                    <div class="error"
                         *ngIf="postForm.get('PostSlug').hasError('pattern') && postForm.get('PostSlug').dirty">
                        URL slug must not contain spaces, special characters or capitalization
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Post Content</span>
                    <textarea class="form-control"
                              placeholder="Post Content"
                              formControlName="PostContent">
                    </textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <span>Post Author</span>
                    <input type="text"
                           class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Post Author"
                           formControlName="PostAuthor">
                </div>
            </div>
        </modal-body>
        <modal-footer>
            <div>
                <a class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal.dismiss()">Cancel</a>
                <button type="submit"
                        [disabled]="postForm.invalid"
                        class="btn btn-primary">
                    {{modalBtnTitle}}
                </button>
            </div>
        </modal-footer>
    </form>
</modal>
```

**`partial post.component.ts`**

```
    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.postForm = this.fb.group({
            PostId: [''],
            PostTitle: [
                '',
                [
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.minLength(3)
                ]
            ],
            PostSlug: [
                '',
                [
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9-]+$')
                ]
            ],
            PostContent: [''],
            PostAuthor: ['']
        });

        this.LoadPosts();
    }
```

I would like a default value to be passed if the `PostContent` and `PostAuthor` fields are left empty. One way that I thought would have worked was to have a default value in the template like so:

```
<textarea class="form-control"
    placeholder="Post Content"
    formControlName="PostContent"
    value="Not Set">
```

However this doesn't work and debugging it shows that null is still returned:

[image: It's not passing the value hard-coded(ewww...) in the value attribute]

Just as well, because that solution would have caused a problem anyway if someone decided to type something then delete it.

For reference, here's the whole `post.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from '../Services/post.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalComponent } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { IPost } from '../Models/post';
import { DBOperation } from '../Shared/enum';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Global } from '../Shared/global';

@Component({
    templateUrl: '/app/Components/post.component.html'
})

export class PostComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('modal') modal: ModalComponent;
    posts: IPost[];
    post: IPost;
    msg: string;
    indLoading: boolean = false;
    postForm: FormGroup;
    dbops: DBOperation;
    modalTitle: string;
    modalBtnTitle: string;    

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private _postService: PostService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.postForm = this.fb.group({
            PostId: [''],
            PostTitle: [
                '',
                [
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.minLength(3)
                ]
            ],
            PostSlug: [
                '',
                [
                    Validators.required,
                    Validators.pattern('^[a-z0-9-]+$')
                ]
            ],
            PostContent: [''],
            PostAuthor: ['']
        });

        this.LoadPosts();
    }

    LoadPosts(): void {
        this.indLoading = true;
        this._postService.get(Global.BASE_POST_ENDPOINT)
            .subscribe(posts => { this.posts = posts; this.indLoading = false; },
            error => this.msg = <any>error);
    }

    addPost() {
        this.dbops = DBOperation.create;
        this.SetControlsState(true);
        this.modalTitle = "Add New Post";
        this.modalBtnTitle = "Add";
        this.postForm.reset();
        this.modal.open();        
    }

    editPost(id: number) {
        this.dbops = DBOperation.update;
        this.SetControlsState(true);
        this.modalTitle = "Edit Post";
        this.modalBtnTitle = "Update";
        this.post = this.posts.filter(x => x.PostId == id)[0];
        this.postForm.setValue(this.post);
        this.modal.open();
    }

    deletePost(id: number) {
        this.dbops = DBOperation.delete;
        this.SetControlsState(false);
        this.modalTitle = "Confirm Post Deletion?";
        this.modalBtnTitle = "Delete";
        this.post = this.posts.filter(x => x.PostId == id)[0];
        this.postForm.setValue(this.post);
        this.modal.open();
    }

    SetControlsState(isEnable: boolean) {
        isEnable ? this.postForm.enable() : this.postForm.disable();
    }

    onSubmit(formData: any) {
        this.msg = "";

        switch (this.dbops) {

            case DBOperation.create:
                this._postService.post(Global.BASE_POST_ENDPOINT, formData._value).subscribe(
                    data => {
                        if (data == 1) //Success
                        {
                            this.msg = "Post successfully added.";
                            this.LoadPosts();
                        }
                        else {
                            this.msg = "There is an issue with creating the post, please contact the system administrator!"
                        }

                        this.modal.dismiss();
                    },
                    error => {
                        this.msg = error;
                    }
                );
                break;

            case DBOperation.update:
                this._postService.put(Global.BASE_POST_ENDPOINT, formData._value.PostId, formData._value).subscribe(
                    data => {
                        if (data == 1) //Success
                        {
                            this.msg = "Post successfully updated.";
                            this.LoadPosts();
                        }
                        else {
                            this.msg = "There is an issue with updating the post, please contact the system administrator!"
                        }

                        this.modal.dismiss();
                    },
                    error => {
                        this.msg = error;
                    }
                );
                break;

            case DBOperation.delete:
                this._postService.delete(Global.BASE_POST_ENDPOINT, formData._value.PostId).subscribe(
                    data => {
                        if (data == 1) //Success
                        {
                            this.msg = "Post successfully deleted.";
                            this.LoadPosts();
                        }
                        else {
                            this.msg = "There is an issue with deleting the post, please contact the system administrator!"
                        }

                        this.modal.dismiss();
                    },
                    error => {
                        this.msg = error;
                    }
                );
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Should I look into adding the Null check in the `onSubmit` method (or is it function?) instead?

---

> Potential solution, needs improvement

So in the `addPost()` part of the `post.component.ts` above, I added two lines:

```
    addPost() {
        this.dbops = DBOperation.create;
        this.SetControlsState(true);
        this.modalTitle = "Add New Post";
        this.modalBtnTitle = "Add";
        this.postForm.reset();
        this.modal.open();
        this.postForm.controls['PostContent'].setValue('not set'); //this here is the magic
        this.postForm.controls['PostAuthor'].setValue('not credited'); // and this too
    }
```

This basically sets the value from the moment the modal box to enter a new entry is loaded. The value can be deleted from the input and when that happens it's replaced with an empty string. I don't know where this empty string value is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I've found an elegant solution for this. Basically, I need to set the initial value when the form is loaded. To do this, I add use the setValue method for the form controls.

```
addPost() {
    this.dbops = DBOperation.create;
    this.SetControlsState(true);
    this.modalTitle = "Add New Post";
    this.modalBtnTitle = "Add";
    this.postForm.reset();
    this.modal.open();
    this.postForm.controls['PostContent'].setValue('not set'); //this here is the magic
    this.postForm.controls['PostAuthor'].setValue('not credited'); // and this too
}
```

Doing this seemed to have solved it in a clunky way. The value is pre-populated in the relevant input fields and if it is deleted, then the value becomes an empty string. This is not ideal.

So I flipped it around and did it this way:

```
    this.postForm.controls['PostContent'].setValue('');
    this.postForm.controls['PostAuthor'].setValue('');
```

Here I set the value to an empty string. It's not null, but the input fields are not pre-populated and my `placeholder` value is still visible. Excellent. But what about the empty string?

We handle that before the data gets passed to the service that does the HttpPost.

```
onSubmit(formData: any) {
    this.msg = "";

    if (formData._value.PostContent == "")
    {
        this.postForm.controls['PostContent'].setValue('not set');
    }
    if (formData._value.PostAuthor == "") 
    {
        this.postForm.controls['PostAuthor'].setValue('not credited');
    }   
    . . .
```

What happens is if the value being passed for those specific keys is an empty string, then set the value to the default.

I think this is a great way to handle this. It's clean and though I am not sure if it's possible to do this, in theory it should not be difficult to put all the default values in a key-value-pair array and access it that way.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of what 'form' (reactive or template driven) you are using, if all you want is to have a default value whenever the input becomes empty, you can make use of the `ngModelChange` event. Have to import `FormsModule` though to your module (where you use this component having this template as its view) for it to work. Use `ngModel` to pass the initial value, if you have any.

> component

```
// define the type 
postAuthorInitValue: string;
postAuthorDefaultValue = 'DEFAULT VALUE';
// or initialize it with a value, assign the right type (here I used string type)
// postAuthorInitValue = 'Abc Xyz';

postAuthorChanged(newVal: string): void {
 if (newVal) {
  this.postAuthorInitValue = newVal;
 } else if (newVal === '') {
  // here is where we put the default value when the 'newVal' is empty string
  this.postAuthorInitValue = this.postAuthorDefaultValue;
 } else {
   this.postAuthorInitValue = newVal;
 }
}
```

> template

```
<input type="text"
                           [ngModel]="postAuthorInitValue"
                           (ngModelChange)="postAuthorChanged($event)"
                           class="form-control"
                           placeholder="Post Author"
                           formControlName="PostAuthor">
```

Another option would be to use a custom directive that can be placed on every `<input type="text">` element that reads its value and a default value and sets the default value to the element whenever the field becomes empty.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You know, this looks so logical and reasonable, but it's still passing a null, and it throws a new error now:

ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: 'DEFAULT VALUE'.

Comment: Could you show your relevant code sections to check it out?

Comment: Which part? I've included the entire post.component.ts at the bottom of the OP.

Comment: I appreciate you trying to help but it's still passing on null. Here's a screenshot of the developer console with a breakpoint set to determine what's being passed: https://i.imgur.com/MnW6gxX.png

Comment: could you show me your template code for the corresponding formControls? I assumed you were passing an initial value.

Comment: It's up there in the `post.component.html`. No initial value is passed. But it's fine, I think I may have found a solution. Let me compose the response and post it shortly.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Ok thought this would be easier, but I was wrong.

You'd probably need something like a function `checkme()` in your TS file that is called when your submit button is called, `<button (click)="checkme()">Submit</button>` that checks:

```
checkme() {
    if (TitleText===null) {
       TitleText = 'default value';
    }
 }
```

or something.

**Irrelevant below but might be useful**

If you have:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="TitleText">
```

Then running

`{{TitleText || 'placeholder'}}`

will give you the string 'placeholder' if the input box is empty (TitleText is null).

It would be the same principle with number inputs where you'd put:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="mynumber">
```

and writing

```
{{mynumber || 0}}
```

to get 0 as a placeholder instead of NaN

Comment: But that's the code to replicate the input from the PostTitle to PostSlug, then pipe it through a custom pipe that removes special characters and add dashes where there was whitespace. It's not the same, although I think there is a way to use the `[(ngModel)]` directive to reference an internal model for default values. Hmmm, something to think about.

Comment: Yeah that's not working. I'm getting a whole bunch of errors here:

Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token '=' at column 25 in [PostContent || 'not set'=$event] in ng:///app/Components/post.component.html...... Directive DefaultValueAccessor.....