# how to bind date/time form control?

Tags: angular, typescript

Here is my simple code that works only for 'title'. 'docdatetime' control appears blank. What am I doing wrong?

```
//template ===================================================
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" id="title" formControlName="title" class="form-control">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="datetime-local" id="docdatetime" formControlName="docdatetime" class="form-control">
</div>

//component.ts ===============================================
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
..... 

export class..... 
    docForm: FormGroup;

    ngOnInit() {
        let docTitle = 'My first document';
        let docDate = 'Jun 15, 2015, 9:43:11 PM';
        this.docForm = new FormGroup({
            'title': new FormControl(docTitle),
            'docdatetime': new FormControl(new Date(docDate))
        });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: [Check the explanation on below link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77737415/5358299)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason for this error is that the `DatetimeLocal` property on the input requires a very specific format, being `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS`. This format is known as an ISO Date. So to fix your error, you have to pass in a date in that format. HOWEVER, an actual ISO Date's format is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ`. The Z refers to the timezone, which is always zero UTC offset. [Look here for information on `ToISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). So, an easy fix for that is to simply slice off the last character, which will always be the character `Z` in the `new Date().toISOString()`.

```
let docTitle = 'My first document';
let docDate = 'Jun 15, 2015, 21:43:11 UTC'; //You'll want to change this to UTC or it can mess up your date.
this.docForm = new FormGroup({
    'title': new FormControl(docTitle),
    'docdatetime': new FormControl(new Date(docDate).toISOString().slice(0, -1))
});
```

## NOTE

This means that the value you receive from that input will NOT be an actual `Date`. It'll be a string. So if you need it to be a date later on, make sure you create a `New Date()` using the value of the string and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you Jun Kang.. It works perfect.. I just had to restart Visual Studio Code and clean browser's cache..

Comment: Hey if you have a Date prompt (not Date/Time) you will need to do `new Date(this.editProduct.purchasedDate).toISOString().substr(0, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the `ngOnInit` part to the following:

```
this.docForm.controls['docTitle'].setValue('My first document');
this.docForm.controls['docDate '].setValue('Jun 15, 2015, 9:43:11 PM');
```

Comment: I'd like to use FormGroup/FormControl concept

Comment: This is using the concept. This solution is based on a similar problem I had here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46457401/angular-2-check-if-input-in-reactive-form-is-empty-enter-default-value-if-no-i/46458928#46458928

Edited the answer to "add" instead of change. Basically add this after you have instantiated the formgroup.

Comment: it doesn't work either. Something wrong with the date/time control itself maybe!? When I submit the form I can see in console logs that the value is correct 'Jun 15, 2015, 9:43:11 PM'.. But it's blank in the browser window

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems, I solved it by converting the date/time, before sending to the server.

**Exemple** (UTC Brazil):

typed "**15**/12/2020 **22:30**:00"

result: '2020-12-**16**T**01:30**:00.000Z'

You convert using:

```
var date = new Date('2020-11-06T01:30:00.000Z');
console.log(date.toLocaleDateString());
console.log(date.toLocaleString());
console.log(date.toLocaleTimeString());
```